# Confirming someone downloaded an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want someone to complete a registration process on a website, then download an app from the Apple App Store, however I am unsure how we could track that someone did download an app and tie that download back to the registration.

What is the best I can hope to achieve with this and how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the user is registered with the website in order to use the app?

Comment: Do you want to know they downloaded the app without having them open the application? If not a simple API and reach out from the app would get your job done.

Comment: What do you mean "tie that download back to the registration"? If it's a process that's in your control, you can add a trigger there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them enter some kind of registration code or a username/password combo created on the website. As far as I know, the is no other way since you do not have access to that kind of information from the App Store.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines but hoping there was something easier than adding code to the app just for this purpose.

Comment: I realize your reluctance to add code, but it's probably the only sure-fire way to know. Just tracking whether a user clicked on a link does not in fact verify that the user actually downloaded the app or establish any kind of link between the downloaded app and the user. Also, a reg code or login screen really should not be much work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want analytics tracking per registration.  For that you may consider a B2B app, meaning it's not visible in the app store when you search for it yet, you can point users to a custom itunes url to download the app.  After that you can download iTunes Connect a view active installs.

http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Taps.io - http://blog.tapstream.com/post/40781681789/made-for-apps-taps-io-shortener

In their own words:

> Taps.io is a universal URL shortener that sends web visitors to your app or your website. It also answers the question: 
>   How many of those visitors download and run your app?
>
> Just like Bit.ly, it tracks the number of clicks - but unlike ordinary shorteners it shows the number of app users you get from that link and its overall conversion rate. So use it instead of a naked iTunes link for tweets, email signatures, ads and anywhere else you share your app. You can even use LinkShare with taps.io to recapture affiliate commission.
>
> Taps.io is free for indie devs, with no cap on how many taps.io links you create or how many clicks you generate.